# SysTracer by SysReveal.com clean?

Tags: malware, security, websites, software-security

SysTracer from SysReveal.com (not from www.blueproject.ro) seems to be a very nice tool for live monitoring your system and check what executable files do at your system. I saw some videos on YouTube where sys-admins used it to show e.g. how Ransomware works. In this video on YouTube ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sm5TbBKeFvU ) by the well known company "Trend Micro", they mentioned (at 0:56) the website SysReveal.com, where you can download SysTracer. The website is on Google's SafeBrowsing blacklist and the tool "SysTracer" hits 8 (*.zip) or 9 (*.exe) of 55 at Virustotal.

I would appreciate it, if you check this tool NOR share your thoughts about it.

- Website: sysreveal.com **(Google's SafeBrowsing Alert!)**
- SysTracer:
  hxxp://sysreveal.com/download/SysTracer.zip **(8 of 55 at Virustotal)**

*Image of SysTracer*
[image]